# Tagging a DOM node for future querying

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseevent

I want to be able to 'tag' any position in the browser with the mouse pointer and then being able to highlight this place in the future.

How can I 'capture' this DOM location in a mouseDown event?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'target' property of the MouseEvent to get the top-most element in the DOM at the position where the mouse was clicked.

```
let highlightedEl;

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
   highlightedEl = event.target;
});
```